# Authenticating with Linkedin using python-social-auth

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm looking to allow users to sign into my web app either by creating a profile (done through `django.contrib.auth`), or using LinkedIn (done through `python-social-auth`).

Relevant file hierarchy is as follows:

```
.
├── ./app
│   ├── ./app/admin.py
│   ├── ./app/forms.py
│   ├── ./app/__init__.py
│   ├── ./app/models.py
│   ├── ./app/serializers.py
│   ├── ./app/templates
│   │   ├── ./app/templates/app
│   │   │   ├── ./app/templates/app/app.js
│   │   │   ├── ./app/templates/app/create_profile.html
│   │   │   ├── ./app/templates/app/index.html
│   │   │   ├── ./app/templates/app/login.html
│   │   │   ├── ./app/templates/app/profile.html
│   │   │   ├── ./app/templates/app/signup.html
│   │   │   └── ./app/templates/app/userhome.html
│   ├── ./app/tests.py
│   ├── ./app/urls.py
│   ├── ./app/views.py
├── ./proj
│   ├── ./proj/settings.py
│   ├── ./proj/urls.py
│   ├── ./proj/wsgi.py
└── ./manage.py
```

Thus far, I've added the following entries into my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # Entries for other purposes...
    # ...
    # ...
    'social.apps.django_app.default'
)


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_KEY = '*secret*'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SECRET = '*secret*'
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = [ 'r_basicprofile' ]
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/userhome'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            # Entries for other purposes...
            # ...
            # ...
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
           'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
        ],
        'debug': DEBUG,
    },
},]
```

In `proj/urls.py`, I've added the following entry:

`url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),`

On my `login.html` page, I've added a link:

`<br>Or, <a href="/login/linkedin">sign in with LinkedIn.</a>`

My login view in `app/views.py` looks like this:

```
def login (request):
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                auth_login(request, user)
                return redirect('/userhome/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid login or password')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Missing username or password')
    return render(request, 'app/login.html', {'form': form})
```

Currently, my "sign in with LinkedIn" link fails to get picked up by the `python-social-auth` backend. As pointed out in [this tutorial](http://artandlogic.com/2014/04/tutorial-adding-facebooktwittergoogle-authentication-to-a-django-application/), I've confirmed that `python-social-auth`'s backend is working: I can see empty tables on the site's admin page.

I've read the following tutorials or SO entries to try and answer my question:

1. [Using python-social-auth with linkedin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26501961/using-python-social-auth-with-linkedin)
2. [Python Social Auth Django template example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995917/python-social-auth-django-template-example)
3. https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html
4. https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/examples/django_example/example/settings.py

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

*from [here](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/linkedin.html)*

Change:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile']
```

to:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile']
```

you might want to use the following as well:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address', 'headline', 'industry']
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA      = [
    ('id', 'id'),
    ('first-name', 'first_name'),
    ('last-name', 'last_name'),
    ('email-address', 'email_address'),
    ('headline', 'headline'),
    ('industry', 'industry')
]
```

*(though I'm having problems getting the email address)*

**Found the solution for missing emails**

Add the following to you `settings.py` file:

```
FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address',]
```

Comment: You saved my life man, thank you! `FIELD_SELECTORS = ['email-address',]` works like a charm!

Comment: Do you know how to get the linkedIn URL?

Comment: from the LinkedIn API documentation